# i get this output instead of the number output i input in androidx.appcompat.widget.appcompatedittext

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, developer-tools

My Github:
https://github.com/Berkayszk/ArtBookTesting/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/artbooktesting/viewmodel/ArtViewModel.kt

Full output - androidx.appcompat.widget.appcompatedittext{2100e7f vfed..cl. .f...... 143,862-573,952 #7f080202 app:id/yeartext aid=1073741837} -

I'm making a work of art recording application. When I want to add my arts, I have to press the save button. There are 3 tracks that I checked while pressing the Save button Name, Artist Name, Year. The error I'm encountering is that no matter what I type in the Year section, I don't get the "Year Should be number.." error. When I put a break point in my program, I get the output I mentioned above in my year text. Because of this, I cannot convert my year value to an int value and my program is constantly giving an error, I cannot add art.

**My ArtViewModel**

```
   private var insertArtMsg = MutableLiveData<Resource<Art>>()
val insertArtMessage : LiveData<Resource<Art>>
    get() = insertArtMsg

//Solving the navigation bug
fun resetInsertArtMsg() {
    insertArtMsg = MutableLiveData<Resource<Art>>()
}

fun setSelectedImage(url : String) {
    selectedImage.postValue(url)
}

fun deleteArt(art: Art) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.deleteArt(art)
}

fun insertArt(art: Art) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.insertArt(art)
}

fun makeArt(name : String, artistName:String, year: String) {

    if (name.isEmpty() || artistName.isEmpty() || year.isEmpty() ) {
        insertArtMsg.postValue(Resource.error("Enter name, artist, year", null))
        return
    }
    val yearInt =try {
        year.toInt()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        insertArtMsg.postValue(Resource.error("Year should be number..",null))
        return
    }

    val art = Art(name, artistName, yearInt,selectedImage.value?: "")
    insertArt(art)
    setSelectedImage("")
    insertArtMsg.postValue(Resource.success(art))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using year.toInt which after try block it converts it integer you should use if block and check int as variable true. unless it stored as zero. You can catch zero as unwanted variable for entry.

Comment: Should I check with if before converting year to int? When I try to put a blockpoint, I give a number to the year, for example 1940, but it does not take this number as an int, it takes the output I gave above.

Comment: You want to catch error and make it say "should be number" print or you want to be able to enter an integer in year input? Like 1980

Comment: I solved the problem, there is no mistake in this part. The problem is yeartext.text should be, but I wrote it as yeartext.